# Receive email in TFS when I have a new task

Tags: tfs, alerts

Is there a way to receive an alert (email) in TFS whenever I have a new task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TFS 2008: right-click project, Project Alerts and check "When my workitems are changed by others"

Comment: Thanks.  I just dug deeper and it appears it is that simple.  I thought there was a way to get more types of alerts to appear.

Comment: There are a number of other alerts available, but not in the GUI.  This is a good article on the command-line for different alerts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx

Answer (score 6):

[Team Foundation Power Tools - Alerts Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vstudio/bb980963.aspx)

"Alerts Editor
 A GUI tool plug-in to Visual Studio that supports flexible subscription of alerts based on check-in, work item change, or build completion."

Answer (score 1):

For TFS 2010 there is an easy solution for you now, via a plugin which can be downloaded from
[CodePlex - Team Alert](http://teamalert.codeplex.com/releases/view/62897)

It's a simple copy-paste solution which can take you 5 minutes to put in place using the configuration extract listed in the post below. This plugin will also enable this rule to any user in the assigned to value, as opposed of setting up an alert for each user individually.

This post will show the exact configuration you need to perform the alert notification.
[Notify AssignedTo user of new work (for a specific TFS project)](http://teamalert.codeplex.com/discussions/355057#post893398)